# Use casperjs to login a website

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I want to use casperjs to login this website
http://forum.ngocrongonline.com/app/login.php

Here is my `test.js` file:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start("http://forum.ngocrongonline.com/app/login.php", function () {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    this.echo('Start to login ...');
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.echo("Filling username and password ...");

    this.fillSelectors('form[name="login"]', { 
        'input[name="user"]': '<< my email >>',
        'input[name="pass"]': '<< my password >>',
        'input[name="server"]': '2'
    }, true);

    this.echo('Finish filling username and password!');
});

casper.thenEvaluate(function () {
    document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').submit();
    this.capture('pic1.png', {
        top: 100,
        left: 100,
        width: 500,
        height: 400
    });
    this.echo('Finish capturing picture');
});


casper.run();
```

However, when I try to run the script, it seems that the script doesn't run the `casper.thenEvaluate` part. Therefore, I cannot capture a picture to see if I really logged in.
Can anybody explain how to complete this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`casper.evaluate()` provides access to the sandboxed DOM context (page context) in PhantomJS and CasperJS. `this` inside of `evaluate()` refers to the global object which is `window` and not `casper`. You cannot have access to `casper` or any other variable defined outside of the page context and you can only pass primitive object in or out of it (Docs: [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html), [CasperJS](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)).

Since the operation that you want to do is synchronous, you can simply move it out of the function:

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function () {
    document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').submit();
});
casper.then(function () {
    this.capture('pic1.png', {
        top: 100,
        left: 100,
        width: 500,
        height: 400
    });
    this.echo('Finish capturing picture');
});
```